# change top position for mousemove() container with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, containers, mousemove

Could anyone please help telling me how to change the y-position for this mousemove-container.

```
container.find(".item_over").mousemove(function(e) { 
        var offset = container.offset();
        x = e.pageX - offset.left;
        var currentZone = Math.floor(x / zoneWidth);
        $(this).find("li").css("display", "none"); 
        $(this).find("li:eq(" + currentZone + ")").css("display", "block"); 
    });
```

Thank you guys

Comment: What do you like to do? Move the container vertically after the mouse cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
container.find(".item_over").mousemove(function(e) { 
    var offset = container.offset(),  //comma to seperate variables
        x = e.pageX - offset.left, 
        y = e.pageY - offset.top, //gets Y, not sure how you intend to use it ??
        currentZone = Math.floor(x / zoneWidth);

    $(this).find("li").css("display", "none"); 
    $(this).find("li:eq(" + currentZone + ")").css("display", "block"); 
}); ​
```